# Regex groups not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match & group (*any phrase*)##date##(*any phrase*), but val1 and val2 are empty.

```
Console.WriteLine("Subject: "+line);
Match match = Regex.Match(line, "(.)"+Regex.Escape("##date##")+"(.)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string val1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
string val2 = match.Groups[2].Value;
Console.WriteLine("Line#{0}: {1} Date: {2}", ++lineNo, val1, val2);
```

Console:

```
Subject: http://www.website.com/url/is/masked.htm ##date## 3
Line#25:   Date:
```

Isn't a dot supposed to match anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A dot matches a **single** character other than a newline.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#AnyCharacter) In your case, it matched the space before and after `##date##`. Use the following regular expression instead:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, "(.*) ##date## (.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This matches the entire phrases before and after `##date##`, excluding the single spaces on either side.

Output:

> Line#25: http://www.website.com/url/is/masked.htm Date: 3

Answer (score 2):

Dot matches a single symbol and in your example `##date##` is surrounded by two spaces. Hence your group mathces are `space` and `space`, which looks like "nothing".

Comment: I get it, thanks! `"(.+)" + Regex.Escape("##date##") + "(.+)"`